# Form submit vs. Javascript POST Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a `POST` request with a very simple HTML `form`. The request fails in the `form` format, but works in Javascript.

It's very simple, so here is almost the entire form:

```
<form method="post" action="[apiUrl]" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="payload" value="[payload]">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

**Please note that `[apiUrl]` and `[payload]` are variables that are injected into the HTML.*

The request fails with a custom message from the API (seems it can't parse the payload):

```
{
  "Error": {
    "Message": "Noun and Verb are Required Request Parameters",
    "ValidationError": false
  },
  "Result": "ERROR"
}
```

However, **the exact same request will succeed when performed by Javascript** (I've tested with both Axios and jQuery, and also with Paw).

```
$.post(this.apiUrl, this.payload, response => {
  console.log('Success!', response);
});
```

The `payload` is just a Javascript `Object`. The variables are set like this:

```
this.apiUrl = request.url;
this.payload = JSON.stringify(request.parameters);
```

**Why does it fail as a `form`?**

Comment: The error would imply that you're not sending the `Noun` and `Verb` parameters in your `<form>` submission. Is the `[payload]` value you set an object? If so, that's the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you think that could be because the Noun and Verb are required request parameters?

Comment: @freedomn-m By jove, Watson, I think it might just be.

Comment: What is the HTTP response code for "failures"? What does the response body look like for the JavaScript submission? I suspect it fails for both, but the API is sending a 200 with custom error in the body rather than an appropriate HTTP error code. If that's true, you'd see the error on screen when submitting the form, knowing it failed. But the JS would see the 200 and run your success function, regardless of what's in the response body.

Comment: Compare the raw requests from the Network tab in the inspector. Are both the same format?

Comment: Have you tried it WITHOUT the [target] attribute specified in the <form> element?

Comment: What's `request.parameters`?  Would expect something like `JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray());` there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it's an object. `this.payload = JSON.stringify(request.parameters);`

@freedomn-m I tried `POST`. No dice.

@JAAulde It's all 200. Failure gives me the JSON response specified. Success gives me a raw PDF stream. :/

@ProEvilz They aren't the same since what shows up in the network tab is successful, which is PDF gibberish.

Comment: That's the problem then. In the form you're sending the JSON string. In the AJAX request you're sending form-urlencoded data. As others have said, inspect the request in the network tab of the console and you'll see the difference and what needs to change

Comment: Ok, my suspicions were confirmed by your comment above. Your API should _not_ send HTTP 200 codes when it fails validation. *BOTH* versions of form submission are failing validation, but the JS doesn't know about it because the server says "Ok" via its status code. JS/AJAX can't possibly know that the custom response body is an error--you have to write code to figure that out. If you don't have control over the API response codes, then you need to adjust your JS success function to look at the response body and analyze whether the server sent an error therein.

Comment: So my comments answer the question as to why one _appears_ to succeed and the other fails. As for why they're failing, we'd need to see the form validation code and actual transmitted data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I met similar problem when I was building the back-end(using Node&Express.js) and front-end(Angular.js) separately using JSON apis.  And it took 12 hours to find the reason why not working with html forms.
The problem was on the back-end side, when you submit using jquery `$.post`, Content-type is `application/json` but when you submit using html `form` Content-type is `application/form-data`.

You can test the APIs using `postman`, if you select the content-type as `form-data` that api will not work.

So to solve the problem, you have to rebuild backend apis to be compatable with Content-type `application/form-data`.

Additionally in my case, I used `body-parser` node package to analyze form data.